# how to set Primary Menu in wpmu automatically

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

when we create sub domain in wpmu the we create four page home,about,team,and contact.
page is created successfully.
But how to select these pages on Primary Menu.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can set menu name in header.php file and when you add that menu in given menu it automatically showing in wordpress

```
    <?php wp_nav_menu( 
        array( 'menu' => 'primary', // menu name in wordpress
        'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); 

?>
```

it is very simple and you need not to set again and agin just carefully you menu name is primary or header or whatever.